# QImage is getting an error eventhough I'm preventing it

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qimage

I'm playing around with QImage and QGraphics view. I was trying to calculate the euclidean distance between two images, I know it's slow but it doesn't matter, and i'm getting this error

```
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::at: "index out of range", file c:\work\build\qt5_workdir\w\s\qtbase\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 377
```

whenever I got through these lines

```
for(int row = 0; row < 128 ; row++){
    for(int col = 0; col < 128; col++){
        if(this->Imagem->valid(row, col)){
            qDebug() << "1";
            this->Imagem->pixel(row, col);
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "2";
    }
}
```

It always outputs "1" on terminal and crashes. I'm declaring the image with

```
this->Imagem = new QImage(128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
this->Imagem->fill(QColor(Qt::black).rgb());
```

and i'm even checking if the points are within the boundaries of the image and it clearly is.

Comment: It crashes at `this->Imagem->pixel(row, col);`

Comment: Start with figuring out the value of row and col when it crashes.  When you run it in a debugger, are this and Imagem also valid?  What is Imagem->size() inside that loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Format_Indexed8** uses the manually defined color table where each index represents a color. You have to set the color table for your image before manipulating its pixels:

```
QVector<QRgb> color_table;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    color_table.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i)); // Fill the color table with B&W shades
}
Imagem->setColorTable(color_table);
```

Or you can manually set each index for the current color table:

```
Imagem->setColorCount(4); // How many colors will be used for this image
Imagem->setColor(0, qRgb(255, 0, 0));   // Set index #0 to red
Imagem->setColor(1, qRgb(0, 0, 255));   // Set index #1 to blue
Imagem->setColor(2, qRgb(0, 0, 0));     // Set index #2 to black
Imagem->setColor(3, qRgb(255, 255, 0)); // Set index #3 to yellow
Imagem->fill(1); // Fill the image with color at index #1 (blue)
```

As you can see, **Format_Indexed8** pixel values represent *not* RGB colors but the index values (which in turn represent the colors you set in the color table).

If you don't want to deal with color tables, you can simply use another format such as **Format_RGB32**.

Comment: I had filled the whole image with black pixels on `this->Imagem->fill(QColor(Qt::black).rgb());`

Comment: `Format_Indexed8` has to be filled not with color values, but with **index** values. That is why you'll need the color table where each index represents a single color. For example, `Imagem->fill(0)` means not "Fill the image with black color", but **"Fill the image with the 0 index and take the color at 0 index from color table"**. Try the code from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `QImage::valid` expects `(col, row)`, not `(row, col)` (i.e. the first parameter is **X**, the second **Y**); this shouldn't however make a difference for a 128x128 image.

May be the object you are accessing has already been destroyed (for example because your handling of ownership is buggy), but it's hard to tell without seeing more code.

Comment: I'll just change my whole code. There isn't much done